# I have an issue with closing many forms at once c#

Tags: c#, windows

In my program I have a main form that opens a new one and than I don't need to use the 1st one so what I want is when I close the 2nd form automaticaly the 1st one closes

Comment: Set owner of the 2nd form: .Show(1st)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following when opening the child form (named FormChild):

```
        FormChild f = new FormChild();
        f.Owner = this;
        f.Show();
```

This will call the closing event of your child form automatically, when main form is closing.